# Ruby on Rails blog with authors

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to do a rails blog that will have author pages where the author will be linked to all of the posts that author has made to the blog. So there will be a main page of blog posts that have been contributed, and I can click on any post to read it, and also click on the author of any post to see that author's page. Which would list all of the article that the author has contributed.

I am following one of the many tutorial's online for creating ruby blogs http://sixrevisions.com/web-development/how-to-create-a-blog-from-scratch-using-ruby-on-rails, but the example they use only links posts to comments. I dont want comments, but instead want posts to be linked to an author. I am obviously very new at rails and have not been able to wrap my mind around why my structure does not work. When I try to submit a new blog post I get the error

```
        "Author(#-607384868) expected, got String(#-604052448)"
```

The blog I was using gives the following examples commands to create the posts and comments.

```
ruby script/generate scaffold post title:string body:text
ruby script/generate scaffold comment name:string body:text post:references
```

I am trying to use

```
ruby script/generate scaffold post title:string body:text author:reference
ruby script/generate scaffold author name:string bio:text posts:references
```

but this is obviously not working. Could someone please point me in the correct direction to create the proper relationship between posts and authors? Thanks ahead of time

*EDIT*
  I put these in a comment below but they may be hard to read. Some of my files are as follows:
routes.rb

```
ActionController::Routing::Routes.draw do |map|
map.resources :posts, :belongs_to => :author
map.connect ':controller/:action/:id'
map.connect ':controller/:action/:id.:format'
map.root :controller => "posts"
end
```

post.rb

```
belongs_to :author
```

author.rb

```
has_many :posts
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you have got field like

```
<%= f.author ... %>
```

and you should use

```
<%= f.author_id ... %>
```

**And there is an error in your generator:**

```
ruby script/generate scaffold post title:string body:text author:reference
```

you need to ad "s" to `reference`

```
ruby script/generate scaffold post title:string body:text author:references
```

so it will work

Comment: okay so I fixed the error in the generator. But I think before I move on to calling the author_id I think I still have other problems. I currently have post.rb saying "belongs_to :author" and author.rb says "has_many :posts" is this correct or no?

Comment: another things that may be helpful is that my routes.rb file is currently ' ActionController::Routing::Routes.draw do |map|
  map.resources :posts, :belongs_to => :author
  map.connect ':controller/:action/:id'
  map.connect ':controller/:action/:id.:format'
  map.root :controller => "posts"
end '